# Deploying NestJS Backend on Vercel/Planetscale VS AWS EC2/EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nestjs, vercel, planetscale

I'm trying to find a correct stack to deploy my backend (BE) service on. Just a note my backend will have roughly 1-3 daily users so the traffic is really low.
What's familiar to be would be to spin up an AWS EC2 instance, run my BE on it, connect it to an EBS instance with SQLite (or AWS EC2 running mySQL with an EBS attached) and call it a day. 
But while I was snooping around for a cheaper option, I've found out that you can deploy NestJS BE on Vercel via their edge functions ([guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-your-nestjs-apps-on-vercel-3431b9f2b4c6)). However I'm not too sure how pricing will be like because it's traditionally used to host frontend applications. But, in my head, it seems like with my really low daily user count I'll probably stay within the free limits. The plan for the database would be to hook it up with PlanetScale (which from my estimates will remain in free tier as well). 
So my question (for my 1-3 daily user app) is:

1. Pros and Cons of hosting BE service on Vercel vs EC2?
2. Pros and Cons of using Planetscale vs SQLite on AWS EBS?
3. Should I host my BE/DB combo on Vercel/Planetscale or AWS EC2/EBS?